# Javascript Numbers and Comma with input pattern

Tags: javascript, html, regex, mobile

Hi I need to combine 2 error checking procedures. I dont use jquery
I only want these values appear 0123456789,

My HTML, i need to know the pattern for other instances of my website

```
<input type="text" pattern="?" maxlength="10" id="f2f11c3" value="0"></input>
```

My JS

```
document.getElementById("f2f11c3").addEventListener("keyup", function(){addcommas("f2f11c3")}, false);
```

.

```
function addcommas(id)
{
//i dont know what to place here
//every 3 numbers must have a comma
//ie. input is 123.c39,1mc 
//it must also remove if a comma is placed manually
//result must be 123,391
}
```

Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely unclear as to what are you asking.

Comment: Basically what you are doing is: Iterate over all characters and keep all numbers and discard everything else. Then iterate backwards over this number and add a comma every 3 characters. That should be fairly simple.

Comment: This does not even sound like a useful thing to do. Silently modifying user input client-side is confusing and risky.

Comment: I guess iteration really is the only way, I've seen some answers with regex codes and figured I could use them. I'll post my answer once I've done the code.

Comment: Thanks for the warning Jukka, but this is for a form where in that field a bunch of numbers will always be placed. I dont really think people would add commas in themselves. So more of instead of typing 100,000,000 people can just type in 100000000 and they get the double check that 100M is indeed the value by visually seeing 100,000,000

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The id is an HTML element's id, not the value

```
function addcommas(id)
{
//Not really needed, but just to shorten the details below
var x = document.getElementById(id);

//Current value but removes anything aside from numbers 0-9 and comma (not really needed)
var curval = x.value.replace(/[^\d,]/g,'');

//Strips the comma from the current value if someone entered it manually. 
var nocomma = x.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');

//If not blank, prevent NAN error
if (nocomma.length>0)
{
    //Converts text to int
    nocomma = parseInt(nocomma, 10);

    //Dont know why, but doesnt work without this
    nocomma = nocomma+0;

    //Converts it back to string to add the comma
    nocomma = nocomma+"";

    //Adds comma every 3 numbers, I got this from other research, dont know how it works
    x.value = nocomma.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
}
```

}

My Input in the HTML is as follows

```
//for iphone, this will popout the numberpad with choices 0-9 only. Easier to type, better mobile usability.
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="12" id="f2f11c3" value="0"></input>
```

Comment: Would just like to add, this would help in inputting numbers in iphone, will try in android in a bit

    <input type="text" pattern="\d*" maxlength="10" id="f2f11c3" value="0">

Comment: pattern will work, if <input> is in <form>.
For example:
<form>
<input type="text" name="code" pattern="^[0-9]+$" title="Digit code">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

Comment: I didn't put it in form but it works, probably new browsers auto adds them in form element. But it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('f2f11c3').
    addEventListener("input", function(){addcommas();}, false);

function addcommas()
{
    var v = document.getElementById('f2f11c3');
    var t = v.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
        var i,temp='';
        for(i=t.length; i>=0;i-=3){

            if(i==t.length) {
                temp=t.substring(i-3,i);
            }
            else 
            {
                if(t.substring(i-3,i)!="")
                temp = t.substring(i-3,i)+','+temp;
            }
            if(i<0) {temp=t.substring(0,i+3)+','+temp; break;}
        }
    v.value = temp;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tegos/qb604k66/)

Comment: Sorry I think this only adds the comma once, so it wont work for a really long number

Comment: @Patrick,  you saw the demo?

Comment: Look this http://jsfiddle.net/Tegos/qb604k66/3/

Comment: Yup, only adds 1 comma still. Something wrong with my browser? Using chrome. Its ok, problem solved.

Comment: Ups, try this http://jsfiddle.net/Tegos/qb604k66/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
function addcommas(id) {
    var arr = [];

    // loop over the id pushing numbers into the array
    for (var i = 0, l = id.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (id[i] >= 0 && id[i] <= 9) {
            arr.push(id[i]);
        }
    }

    // loop over the array splicing in commas at every 3rd position
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i += 3) {
        arr.splice(i, 0, ',');
        i++;
        l++;
    }

    // remove the first unnecessary comma
    arr.shift()

    // return the comma-separated string
    return arr.join('');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1frzk1x9/)